# Not able to use insert query in oracle database

Tags: python, cx-oracle

```
insert="INSERT INTO Tablename (column1,column2,....) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,...)
vals=(variable1,variabl2,'','',Variable5, '','',...)
c.execute(insert,vals)
```

I am receiving an error stating

> ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

help me resolve this issue
in python

```
DATATYPE            Nullable Column_ID
VARCHAR2(9 BYTE)    No       1  
VARCHAR2(9 BYTE)    Yes      2  
VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)   Yes      3  
VARCHAR2(9 BYTE)    Yes      4  
VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)   Yes      5  
VARCHAR2(9 BYTE)    Yes      6  
VARCHAR2(12 BYTE)   Yes      7  
VARCHAR2(13 BYTE)   Yes      8  
VARCHAR2(14 BYTE)   Yes      9  
VARCHAR2(9 BYTE)    Yes      10 
VARCHAR2(17 BYTE)   Yes      11 
VARCHAR2(9 BYTE)    Yes      12 
VARCHAR2(17 BYTE)   Yes      13
```

Comment: maybe a columnname is a keyword

Comment: I am giving column name as per my table

Comment: but backticks ` around each columnname and table

Comment: ('AP_ID','ADRSDD_ID','APAMSN_NM','CERTUSR_ID')

Comment: I have already added the  back ticks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sql variables should start with ":", eg, `:1`, `:2` for tuple or `:age`, `:name` for named arguments

so, the code should be:

```py
insert="INSERT INTO Tablename (column1,column2,....) VALUES (:1,:2,:3,...)"
vals=(variable1,variabl2,'','',Variable5, '','',...)
c.execute(insert,vals)
```

Comment: while trying this :1,:2 it is saying missing SELECT keyword

Comment: Now issue resolved but it is not inserting data

Comment: you should add `c.commit()`

Comment: see https://dbaportal.eu/sidekicks/sidekick-cx_oracle-code-paterns/

Comment: c.commit()
AttributeError: 'cx_Oracle.Cursor' object has no attribute 'commit'

Comment: sorry, use ’connection.commit()‘ instead

Comment: please read this tutorial https://dbaportal.eu/sidekicks/sidekick-cx_oracle-code-paterns/

Comment: It Was working as you suggested but now when I am inserting to another table it is throwing error

Comment: insert="insert into tablename(column 1,column 2,.....) values (:1,:2,:3,%s,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13)"
vals=(variable,variable,98,variable)